# JSON insert error, Sqlite3, Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am trying to insert raw JSON strings into a sqlite database using the sqlite3 module in python.

When I do the following:

```
rows = [["a", "<json value>"]....["n", "<json_value>"]]
cursor.executemany("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO FEATURES(UID, JSON) VALUES(?, ?)""", rows)
```

I get the following error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current statement uses 2, and there are 48 supplied.

How can I insert the raw json into a table?  I assume it's the commas in the json string.

How can I get around this?

Comment: I have a list of multiple rows to insert, so isn't a list or lists the proper way to use that function?>\

Comment: Your list doesn't look like you think it looks like; or at least not like the example you gave here. The sqlite module tells you it has 48 values instead of two so you better believe it... I suggest you print your list prior to insertion to see what's really inside.

Comment: Either you have a problem in your nested lists (most likely what you think is a single string json value has really been parsed into 47 items) or else you're mistakenly calling `execute()` instead of `executemany()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is interpreted as a list of characters (that's where the '48 supplied' is coming from - 48 is the length of the `<json value>` string).

You will be able to pass your input in as a string if you wrap it in square brackets like so

```
["<json value>"]
```

The whole line would then look like

```
rows = [["a", ["<json value>"]]....["n", ["<json value>"]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Second argument passed to [`executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) has to be list of touples, not list of lists:

```
[tuple(l) for l in rows]
```

From [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module documentation:

> Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then
>   provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s
>   [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method.

The same applies to [`executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany).

Comment: Lists are perfectly valid as parameter containers in Python / SQLite.

Answer (score -2):

It's kind of a long shot... but perhaps you could quote the JSON values to ensure the parsing works as desired:

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO FEATURES(UID, JSON) VALUES(?, '?')""", rows)
```

EDIT: Alternatively... this might force the json into a sting in the insertion?

```
rows = [ uid, '"{}"'.format( json_val ) for uid, json_val in rows ]
cursor.executemany("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO FEATURES(UID, JSON) VALUES(?, ?)""", rows)
```

Comment: You don't seem to know how prepared statements work - this is obviously wrong as sqlite takes care of the parameter bindings and there is no need to escape anything.